# Issue with the rails (2.3.11) server(production side)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am stuck with a very unusual issue. I am trying to call a webservice request from the server (actully an ajax 2 step request from the client side) for which i am getting an xml formatted response which i am parsing using a treeview. The issue is..its working well in development mode on local server but showing error in production with the same codes. When I initiate a request I get a response for the first step in string format but showing error "error loading xmlDoc: xmlDoc is undefined" for the second request which suppose to be initiated directly after the first response.

codes are available here: 
https://github.com/domthu/microaquadt/blob/master/app/views/oligo_sequences/edit.html.erb

error is somewhere on the function starting from line 195.

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated...!!!!

Comment: You have many missing `;`s in your `<script>`

Comment: still behaving as before.. even after adding all the missing ;s...!!!